# Cannot load image from Zend server

Tags: ios, zend-framework, https, xamarin.ios, nsdata

I cannot load image from Zend server with following code:

```
Console.WriteLine(">" + url);
Console.WriteLine(">" + NSUrl.FromString(url));
Console.WriteLine(">" + NSData.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromString(url))); // Null on this line
```

It appears only when I'm trying to load image from my server, any other source works fine. Here is my Zend controller code:

```
public function getAction()
{
    $file_id = (int)$this->_getParam('id');
    $file = $this->fileModel->getById($file_id);

    $this->getResponse()
        ->setHttpResponseCode(200)
        ->setHeader('Pragma', 'public', true)
        ->setHeader('Expires', '', true)
        ->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public', true)
        ->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=3800')
        ->setHeader('Content-type', $file->CONTENT_TYPE, true)
        ->setHeader('Content-Length', $file->FILE_SIZE)
        ->clearBody();
    $this->getResponse()->sendHeaders();

    echo base64_decode($file->FILEBODY);
    exit;
}
```

Image showed fine in browser. What's wrong with my code?

PS: my server works throught HTTPS without any signed certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSData.FromUrl` ([`dataWithContentsOfURL:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL%3a) in Objective-C) will return `null` for any error.

From Apple documentation:

> Returns nil if the data object could not be created.

So something went wrong...

> PS: my server works throught HTTPS without any signed certificate

Doubtful. You likely have a self-signed certificate (or your server should not be happy). Anyway...

If, when trying your URL, Safari (from your iPhone/iPad) warns you about your site then it falls into the *something went wrong* category and the `null` value you get is normal.

You might want to try HTTP: to make sure it's not related to something else (e.g. networking issues).

Now if you **really* want to use an untrusted SSL server you can use some .NET API, e.g. [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f.aspx).

```
 var wc = new WebClient ();
 byte[] data = wc.DownloadData (url);
```

That alone will get you an exception (untrusted SSL server) but IMO that's already better than simply a `null`.

Next you'll need to vouch for the untrusted certificate. There's a few different ways to do it (some much better than others). I fairly complete list of them (with source) code can be found in this [article](http://www.mono-project.com/UsingTrustedRootsRespectfully).